# Live streaming from Android app to Youtube

Tags: android, youtube, streaming, video-streaming, youtube-api

**Is it possible to stream video from Android app to Youtube in live mode (to live channel on Youtube)?**

I would like to do that but by streaming a previously-saved file from the Android device (not streaming video from the device's camera).

I'm looking for the simplest solution to do that (without a need for any intermediate servers, etc.), specifically for the purpose of streaming from Android (but the question is more about Youtube API).

If it is possible, where should I start with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**  Unless you are an offical YouTube partner on their magic happy list.  They know who they are, and it doesn't sound like you are one of them.   Sorry.

From an announcement on [their blog](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2011/04/youtube-is-going-live.html):

> Today, we'll also start gradually rolling out our live streaming beta
>   platform, which will allow **certain YouTube partners** with accounts in
>   good standing to stream live content on YouTube.

Remember that [Youtube Live](http://www.youtube.com/live) is only a year old.  The state of things very well may change in the short to medium term future.

In the mean time, have a look at services that may meet your needs, like [justin.tv](http://justin.tv) or [ustream.com](http://ustream.com)

Comment: Is this still true on 2015?

Comment: You can live stream private and unlisted videos no problem. It's only public live streaming that requires you to be approved as a Youtube partner.

Answer (score 3):

[It can be done](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.numedecod.cast) :) To answer the question: you kind of need to dig in very deep into things like MediaCodec, H264 video encoder, Adobe's RTMP specification, the FLV media container format, and several other things.

Disclaimer: I am the author of that app.

Comment: Did you have to use NDK (JNI) to send data to RTMP server?

Comment: @TOP - No, everything is done in Java with a custom RTMP client. JNI might be easier for you, but I wanted to avoid the entire memory-copying overheads since Android's MediaCodec already uses direct buffers anyway and the JVM overhead is minimal.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Yes...  if you are willing to pay quite a lot of money.

**There is an app called "Screen Stream Mirroring" available on the Play Store**. There is a limited free version (which I have tried and seems to only stream for around 10 minutes) and there is a paid version, but it's a lot of money for what you're getting: £3.99 (about $6.05 as of 06/09/2015 according to xe.com).

Feel free to try them out: [Click here for free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial) or [Click here for paid version.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream)

Answer (score 1):

You can stream your videos live to hangout and at the end they may be uploaded into your yourtube.

More info:
http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable live streaming on your Youtube account.
But problem is that you need to call someone from Hangouts and that person need to answer your call. Then your stream goes live to Hangouts and your linked Youtube channel. It is impossible to make live stream without at least one person answering that "call".

Answer (score 1):

According to this youtube page, it is possible: http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com.tr/2014/10/watchme-live-stream.html